# ¿Existe esta forma de definir una clase anónima en Java?

Tags: java, clase-anidada

Estaba estudiando un documento de mi clase de programación sobre clases anónimas, pero llegué a una parte que no se si es un error del documento o yo no puedo entender lo que dice:

> Formas de definir una clase anónima:
>
> 1. Las clases anónimas requieren una extensión de la palabra clave new. Se definen en una expresión de Java, incluida en una asignación o
>    en la llamada a un método. Se incluye la palabra new seguida de la
>    definición de la clase anónima, entre llaves {…}.
> 2. Otra forma de definirlas es mediante la palabra new seguida del nombre de la clase de la que hereda (sin extends) y la definición de
>    la clase anónima entre llaves {…}. El nombre de la super-clase puede
>    ir seguido de argumentos para su constructor (entre paréntesis, que
>    con mucha frecuencia estarán vacíos pues se utilizará un constructor
>    por defecto).
> 3. Una tercera forma de definirlas es con la palabra new seguida del nombre de la interface que implementa (sin implements) y la definición
>    de la clase anónima entre llaves {…}. En este caso la clase anónima
>    deriva de Object. El nombre de la interface va seguido por paréntesis
>    vacíos, pues el constructor de Object no tiene argumentos.

Lo que yo no entiendo bien es el párrafo número 1. Según lo que pude comprender la sintaxis sería más o menos así:

```
MiClase unObjeto = new {//Cuerpo de la clase}
```

Estuve buscando ejemplos tratando de encontrar alguna clase que se defina de esa manera, pero no encontré ninguno, y al tratar de escribir un ejemplo así en NetBeans el programa me marca un error.

Entonces mi duda es: ¿solo se pueden definir clases anónimas como en los puntos 2 y 3?

El documento que me dieron en clases no tiene las fuentes, pero encontré la misma información en [esta página](https://conocimientosweb.net/dcmt/ficha20848.html).

Comment: La importancia de consultar primero la documentación oficial; por descuido o ignorancia ese documento está equivocado. La clase [*Object*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) es la raíz en la jerarquía de clases, así que por muy anónima que sea la clase por lo menos hereda *Object*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Coincido contigo en que lo que aparece en el texto citado es confuso y a mi entender erróneo. La [documentación oficial de Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) al respecto lo deja bastante más claro

> The anonymous class expression consists of the following:
>
> - The `new` operator
> - The name of an interface to implement or a class to extend.
> - Parentheses that contain the arguments to a constructor, just like a
>   normal class instance creation expression. Note: When you implement an
>   interface, there is no constructor, so you use an empty pair of
>   parentheses.
> - A body, which is a class declaration body. More specifically, in the
>   body, method declarations are allowed but statements are not.

Que traducido al español vendría a decir

> La expresión (de instanciación) de una clase anónima consiste en los siguiente:
>
> - El operador `new`
> - **El nombre del interfaz que se implementa o de la clase de la que se hereda.**
> - Paréntesis que pueden contener los argumentos de un constructor, como cualquier instancia de una clase normal. Nota: Cuando implementas un interfaz, no hay constructor, por tanto usaremos un par de paréntesis vacíos.
> - Un cuerpo, que es el cuerpo declarado de una clase. Específicamente, en el cuerpo, las declaraciones de métodos están permitidos pero las sentencias no.

Como ves, esas supuestas tres formas diferentes no se distinguen ahí arriba. O heredas de una clase o implementas un interfaz (en negrita arriba). No existe esa tercera posibilidad.

A partir de Java 8 sí aparece una nueva forma, donde NO es necesario el operador `new`, en la que puedes sustituir una clase anónima por una expresión lambda o por una referencia a método.

En el documento que enlazas sí aparece citada la fuente original: *Aprenda Java como si estuviera en primero*. Un manual de Java redactado en la Universidad de Navarra (España) en el año 2000. Puede descargarse completo [aquí](http://ocw.uc3m.es/cursos-archivados/programacion-java/manuales/java2-U-Navarra.pdf/view).

Leyéndolo por encima he visto una referencia a Java 1.1! Quizás en las primeras versiones de Java sí se pudiera emplear esa tercera forma pero el documento está obviamente más que obsoleto en 2021 y no debería usarse como referencia actualmente.

Comment: Te puedo confirmar siquiera en Java 1.1 era así, es un error del documento

Comment: @PabloLozano Gracias por la confirmación, yo empecé con el 1.4 :-)

Comment: Muchas gracias por sacarme de la duda!